# Xcode 6.4 simulator only shows iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I was trying to test my ios application on the iPad 2 simulator in Xcode version 6.4, but it came up with some error saying it couldn't find a file or something (unfortunately I can't get the error to occur again and give the exact message). Then shortly after, I tried again and only iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus show up for simulator options. What could have caused this, and how can I get the other simulation types back working again without losing my current projects?

Comment: Well did my answer work? If yes, please accept it as a valid answer.

Comment: Where exactly do I change the base SDK in the project? If it works I will for sure accept it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your base SDK in the project and see if those simulators come back again or not.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]